# how to make a count function inside another count function work

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to access a variable that i declared in a count function inside another count function but when i call that function, it happens to be undefined as below

```
Found
Notice: Undefined variable: name1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/hello.php on line 32
```

i use the count functions to access various data outputted by an explode function. the exploded data is information from a text file. this is the text file data below

```
Trinity Clare 2019-07-31 F Mary
signature A
```

the code for getting data from the text file and accessing that data is as below

```
 <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','recess') or die('couldnt connect'.mysqli_error());

    //Kampala
    if(file_exists("/opt/lampp/htdocs/Recess/Kampala.txt"))
    {
      $file = fopen("/opt/lampp/htdocs/Recess/Kampala.txt","r");
      while(!feof($file))
      {
        $content = fgets($file);
        $carray = explode(" ", $content);
        //var_dump($carray);
        if(count($carray)==3)
        {
            list($word,$letter) = $carray;
            $sign = "SELECT signature from agents";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sign);
            $data = array();
            while($signature = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $data[] = $signature['signature'];
            }
            if(in_array($letter, $data))
            {
                echo "Found";
                if(count($carray)==5)
                {
                    list($name1,$name2,$date,$gender,$recommender1) = $carray;

                }
                echo $name1;
            }
            else{
                echo "none";
            }
        }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

"Found" is supposed to be returned if letter "A" is found with in the array of data fetched from mysql and first word from the text file is supposed to be printed after assigning it a variable in the second count statement

Comment: Eh? The count of `$carray` can't be 3 _and_ 5... and if it's not 5 (which it can't be because you're inside an if block that specifically checks that it's 3), then you don't define $name1.

Comment: you define $name1 in the if statement and after the if you echo it. You will get this error whenever your if statement is false

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. Also the code is to unclear as alot off infromation is missing..  How the tables look like for example

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you mean my mysql tables?

Comment: *" do you mean my mysql tables?"* yea i meant the MySQL tables columns and data in it..

Comment: the first column is name which is supposed to take both $name1 and $name2, second is date, third is gender and the fourth is recommender

Answer (score 0):

You define `$name1` in the if statement and after the if you echo it.
You will get this error whenever your if statement is false.

You can solve it checking the existance of $name1 variable:

```
echo "Found";
if(count($carray)==5) {
    list($name1,$name2,$date,$gender,$recommender1) = $carray;

}
echo isset($name1) ? $name1 : "<br>Count $carray != 5";
```

Comment: $name1 actually does exist, the issue is that the if statement if(count($carray)==5) {
    list($name1,$name2,$date,$gender,$recommender1) = $carray;

} seems to not work... how can i make it work because i want to insert the data in those variables into a databas

Comment: the error is pretty clear: the $name1 variable is not defined.

Comment: it is defined at this point   list($name1,$name2,$date,$gender,$recommender1) = $carray;

Comment: It's not defined since `count($carray)` does not equal 5 so that line doesn't run.

Comment: but when i transfer it outside the  if(count($carray)==3), it works!!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't @GiacomoM

Comment: Look, `count($carray)` can't give different values if `$carray` doesn't change (which is doesn't in the code in your question). So something you're telling us isn't right afacs.

Comment: @TamaleCollins your question was about the PHP error you get. And my code solve it. Now your problem is different, cause it is about IF statement